# How to get rid of variable amplitude in cosine function using python-scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

after a complex FFT analysis, I got my data as `

```
y=np.array([-0.31757207, -0.759897  , -0.97481323, -0.90067096, -0.56201419,
   -0.06141066,  0.45184696,  0.82654122,  0.95429599,  0.80098432,
    0.41565507, -0.08528661, -0.55350349, -0.85289024, -0.89924892,
   -0.6838725 , -0.27446443,  0.20632688,  0.61789554,  0.84295248,
    0.82091852,  0.56394004,  0.15139964, -0.29481341, -0.64650262,
   -0.80602096, -0.73317927, -0.45486384, -0.0552602 ,  0.3498015 ,
    0.64649953,  0.75486814,  0.64997615,  0.36696461, -0.01077531,
   -0.37629244, -0.62928397, -0.70331519, -0.58277349, -0.30541445,
    0.04956568,  0.38413122,  0.60823604,  0.66362602,  0.53848173,
    0.26941065, -0.06930203, -0.38601383, -0.59612545, -0.6442082 ,
   -0.5182447 , -0.25246689,  0.08181356,  0.39497462,  0.60264688,
    0.6480463 ,  0.51731067,  0.24376628, -0.10019951, -0.42181997,
   -0.63254052, -0.67215727, -0.52601037, -0.23032442,  0.13622702,
    0.47298468,  0.68464621,  0.70816855,  0.53165966,  0.19956061,
   -0.19797826, -0.54920882, -0.75206661, -0.74391156, -0.52103408,
   -0.14180003,  0.28818356,  0.64528143,  0.82341019,  0.76573576,
    0.48295615,  0.05224223, -0.40355087, -0.75089961, -0.88488436,
   -0.76111445, -0.41051563,  0.06797007,  0.53521743,  0.85248562,
    0.92285209,  0.72105995,  0.30251038, -0.21178154, -0.67024193,
   -0.935627  , -0.92637938, -0.64190028, -0.16383967,  0.36735054,
    0.79386302,  0.98768951,  0.88930233,  0.52608786,  0.00477518,
   -0.52006527, -0.89210845, -1.00012051, -0.8114311 , -0.3818889 ,
    0.16075761,  0.65507887,  0.95427369,  0.97001733,  0.69866763,
    0.22200955])
```

Which, when plotted produces this:[image: y]

This is a cosine function with variable amplitude. I'm looking for a way to get rid of the amplitude envelope to obtain normal cosine function which I can fit.

Comment: It appears that you have a "fast" sinusoidal modulated with a "slow" one.  As I understand the question, you want to suppress the envelope, i.e. the slow signal.  If that's the case, compute an FFT of the above signal and zero the coefficients associated with the slower sinuosoidal(s).  Then, compute the IFFT to produce the input signal with the envelope suppressed.

Comment: Thanks @Throwback1986 for the reply. The output y was obtained via ifft where a particular frequency is selected with a width of 1 bin size to filter the data.  The fft resolution is responsible for the amplitude.

Comment: the above procedure should still be sufficient to remove the envelope.  Simple treat your IFFT result above as a "new" signal and then apply the frequency domain manipulation described in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks @Throwback1986, the problem is  now solved. This time I used a Gaussian window of order 2 or higher with a central frequency and small width to  select my fft spectrum. Then I did ifft and it gave a reasonable cosine function.

Comment: Here it is not necessary to place resolved in the title of the question, you must publish a response and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, figure

from numpy import array, exp, arange, real, append

from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft

w = fft(y)

f = arange(0,y.size)

cf = 10 #central freq

wd = 0.5 #width

gate1 = exp(-((f-cf)/(0.707106*wd))**(2*2))

gate2 = append([0],gate1[::-1])[:-1] #symmetrize

gate = gate1+gate2

w_f = w*gate

figure(1)

plot(abs(w))

plot(abs(w_f))

figure(2)

plot(real(ifft(w_f)))